# How to tile a texture for skybox in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox

I have a small image (32x32) and I would like to tile it and use the tiled version for a side in a 6 sided skybox.  I can easily use it as a texture and get a single image to show up for each side of the skybox, but I want the entire side to be tiled.  I tried to create a tiled material, but after I have the material (which is tiled) I cannot use it in the 6 sided skybox because it is not a texture.  Is there a way to tile a skybox if I only have one piece of the pattern.

Comment: Is a good pratice Google it first: https://forum.unity.com/threads/tiled-skybox-shader.226954/ or https://answers.unity.com/questions/53662/how-can-i-tile-a-texture-on-a-skybox.html

Comment: Please post here as an answer when you accomplish this! :D